# Prove $1^2-2^2+3^2-4^2+......+(-1)^{k-1}k^2 = (-1)^{k-1}\cdot \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I'm trying to solve this problem from Skiena book, "Algorithm design manual".

I don't know the answer but it seems like the entity on the R.H.S is the summation for series $1+2+3+..$. However the sequence on left hand side is squared series and seems to me of the form:

$-3-7-11-15\ldots $

I feel like its of the closed form:

$\sum(-4i+1)$

So how do I prove that the equality is right?

Comment: Have you tried to prove it by induction?

Comment: Note that the partial sums on the LHS are $1, -3, 6, -10,\ldots$. I suggest using induction. It might be easier to do it twice: for $k$ odd and for $k$ even.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1445724/interesting-sum-i-0m-1-1im-i2-sum-i-1mi/1445757#1445757

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i) $k=2n$:
\begin{align}
\sum_{m=1}^{2n}(-1)^{m-1}m^2&=\sum_{m=1}^{2n}m^2-2\sum_{m=1}^{n}(2m)^2\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^{2n}m^2-8\sum_{m=1}^{n}m^2\\
&=\frac{2n(2n+1)(4n+1)}{6}-8\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\\
&=\frac{2n(2n+1)(4n+1-4n-4)}{6}\\
&=\frac{2n(2n+1)(-1)}{2}=-\frac{k(k+1)}{2}=(-1)^{k-1}\frac{k(k+1)}{2}
\end{align}
ii)$k=2n+1$:
\begin{align}
\sum_{m=1}^{2n+1}(-1)^{m-1}m^2&=(2n+1)^2+\sum_{m=1}^{2n}(-1)^{m-1}m^2\\
&=(2n+1)^2+\frac{2n(2n+1)(-1)}{2}\\
&=\frac{(2n+1)(4n+2-2n)}{2}=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}=(-1)^{k-1}\frac{k(k+1)}{2}
\end{align}

Answer (score 6):

The following proof might be longer than necessary, but it illustrates a general method that is useful for many similar problems.

Let $$A(k) = 1^2 - 2^2 + 3^2 - 4^2 + \ldots + (-1)^{k-1} k^2$$ and
$$B(k)=(-1)^{k-1} \cdot \frac{k(k+1)}2.$$ It suffices to prove that $A(0)=B(0)$ and $$A(k)-A(k-1)=B(k)-B(k-1)$$ for all $k\ge1$.

It is clear that $A(0)=B(0)=0$.

$$\begin{align*} 
A(k) - A(k-1) &= (-1)^{k-1} k^2 \\
B(k) - B(k-1) &= (-1)^{k-1} \cdot \frac{k(k+1)}2 
- (-1)^{k-2} \cdot \frac{(k-1)k}2 \\
&= (-1)^{k-1} \left(\frac{k(k+1)}2 + \frac{(k-1)k}2 \right) \\
&= (-1)^{k-1} \left(\frac{k^2+k}2 + \frac{k^2-k}2 \right) \\
&= (-1)^{k-1} k^2
\end{align*}
$$

To complete the proof, note that for all $k \ge 0$,
$$
\begin{align*}
A(k) &= A(0) + \sum_{i=1}^k (A(i) - A(i-1)) \\
&= B(0) + \sum_{i=1}^k (B(i) - B(i-1)) \\
&= B(k).
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Proceed inductively. Verify that for $k=1$, $1 = 1$.

Now suppose the result holds for $n - 1$. Then

$$ 1^2 + \dots + (-1)^{n-1} n^2 = 1 + \dots + (-1)^{n-2} (n-1)^2 + (-1)^{n-1} n^2 = (-1)^n \frac{n(n-1)}{2} + (-1)^{n-1} n^2 = (-1)^n \left(\frac{n(n-1)-2n^2}{2}  \right) = (-1)^n \left(\frac{-n^2-n}{2} \right) = (-1)^{n-1} \left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)$$

The induction hypothesis was applied at the second equality.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* In order  to show
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^{j-1}j^2=(-1)^{k-1}\frac{k(k+1)}{2}\qquad\qquad k\geq 0\tag{1}
\end{align*}
we consider sequences $(a_k)_{k\geq 0}$ and the corresponding generating functions $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kx^k$ as *building  blocks* to generate the left hand sum in (1). This enables us to calculate the right hand side of (1).
\begin{array}{crl}
  (a_k)_{k\geq 0}\qquad &\qquad A(x)=&\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kx^k\\
  \hline\\
  ((-1)^{k-1})_{k\geq 0}\qquad&\qquad -\frac{1}{1+x}=&\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k-1}x^k\\
  ((-1)^{k-1} k)_{k\geq 0}\qquad&\qquad -\left(x\frac{d}{dx}\right)\frac{1}{1+x}
  =&\frac{x}{(1+x)^2}\\
&=&\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k-1}kx^k\\
  ((-1)^{k-1} k^2)_{k\geq 0}\qquad&\qquad -\left(x\frac{d}{dx}\right)^2\frac{1}{1+x}
  =&\frac{x(1-x)}{(1+x)^3}\\
&=&\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k-1}k^2x^k\\
  (\sum_{j=0}^{k}(-1)^{j-1} j^2)_{k\geq 0}\qquad&\qquad -\frac{1}{1-x}\left(x\frac{d}{dx}\right)^2\frac{1}{1+x}
  =&\frac{x}{(1+x)^3}\\
&=&\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{k}(-1)^{j-1}j^2\right)x^k\tag{2}\\
  \end{array}

We can see in the small intro above the *operator* $x\frac{d}{dx}$ transforms $a_k$ to $ka_k$ and the *multiplication* with $\frac{1}{1-x}$ acts as *summation operator*.

It is also convenient to use the *[coefficient of](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9402216)* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$ in a generating series.

> We  obtain from (2) for $k\geq 1$
>
> \begin{align*}
>  \sum_{j=0}^{k}(-1)^{j-1}j^2&=[x^k] \frac{-1}{1-x}\left(x\frac{d}{dx}\right)^2\frac{1}{1+x}\\
>  &=[x^k] \frac{x}{(1+x)^3}\\
>  &=[x^{k-1}]\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{-3}{n}x^{n}\tag{3}\\
>  &=\binom{-3}{k-1}\\
>  &=(-1)^{k-1}\binom{k+1}{2}\tag{4}\\
>  &=(-1)^{k-1}\frac{k(k+1)}{2}
>   \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (3) we use the *[binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* representation.
- In (4) we use the formula $\binom{-n}{k}=\binom{n+k-1}{k}(-1)^k$ for *[binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)*.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Distinguish the cases where $n$ is odd or even and use that $-4i+1=(-2i)+(-2i+1)$

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily shown that the series on the left reduces to the sum of integers, multiplied by $-1$ if $k$ is even.

For even $k$: 
$$\begin{align}
&1^2-2^2+3^3-4^2+\cdots+(k-1)^2-k^2\\
&=(1-2)(1+2)+(3-4)(3+4)+\cdots +(\overline{k-1}-k)(\overline{k-1}+k)\\
&=-(1+2+3+4+\cdots+\overline{k-1}+k)\\
&=-\frac {k(k+1)}2\end{align}$$

Similar, for odd $k$, 
$$\begin{align}
&1^2-2^2+3^3-4^2+5^2+\cdots-(k-1)^2+k^2\\
&=1+(-2+3)(2+3)+(-4+5)(4+5)+\cdots +(-\overline{k-1}+k)(\overline{k-1}+k)\\
&=1+2+3+4+\cdots+\overline{k-1}+k\\
&=\frac {k(k+1)}2\end{align}$$

Hence, 
$$1^2-2^2+3^3-4^2+5^2+\cdots+(-1)^{k-1}k^2=(-1)^{k-1}\frac {k(k+1)}2\quad\blacksquare$$

Answer (score 0):

No one's pointing out my favorite result that $n^2$ is the sum of the first odd numbers?

$(n + 1)^2  - n^2 = (n^2 + 2n + 1) - n^2 = 2n + 1$.

and the result follows...

Case 1: $k=2m$ is even.

$1 - 2^2 + 3^2 - 4^2 + .... + (k-1)^2 - (k)^2 = -(2^2 -1) - (4^2 - 3^2) - ...- (k^2 - (k-1)^2)=$

$-(3) - (-7)-....-(2k + 1) = \sum_{j = 1}^m-(4j + 1)=$

$-4(\sum_{j=1}^m j) + m(\sum_{j=1}^m j)=$

$-4(\frac{(m(m+1)}{2}) + (m) = -2m(m+1) + m = m(-2(m+1) + 1) = m(-2m - 1) =$

$ -m(2m + 1)= -\frac{k(k + 1)}{2}$

Case 2:  $k = 2m + 1$ is odd.

$[1 - 2^2 + 3^2 - 4^2 + .... + (k-2^2 - (k-1)^2 ] + k^2 =$

$ -\frac{(k-1)k}{2} + (k^2) = k[-\frac{k-1}{2} + k] =$

$k[\frac{-(k-1)+2k}{2} ]=\frac{k(k + 1)}{2}$

So

sum = $(-1)^{k-1}\frac{k(k + 1)}{2}$